# How to encode 2 objects in the same JSON object usin JBuilder Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

There is the following code using JBuilder:

```
  json.details   place.details

  if (place.type == 'restaurant')
    json.food_types place.details.food_types, :id
  end
```

JSON response:

```
details":{"average_check":100,"id":12},"food_types":[{"id":1}]}
```

Now I need to move food_types to details:

```
details":{"average_check":100,"id":12", food_types":[{"id":1}]}}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can build it like this

```
json.details do 
    json.(place.details, :average_check, :id)
    if (place.type == 'restaurant')
       json.food_types place.details.food_types, :id
    end
  end
end
```

or [Jbuilder objects can be directly nested inside each other. Useful for composing objects.](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)